# How Can I Console.log countdownjs module via node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm using [countdownjs](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs) module

, How Can I Console.log countdownjs for 3 days later, via node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example how you can use the countdown module:

```
var now = new Date();
var durationInDays = 3;
var durationInMilliseconds = (durationInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var future = now.getTime() + durationInMilliseconds;
var countdownInfo = countdown(now, future);

// print it once
console.log(countdownInfo.toString());


// print it every 5 seconds

function repeatedPrint() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // you have to provide a new start date to get updated information
        countdownInfo = countdown(new Date(), future);
        console.log(countdownInfo.toString());
        repeatedPrint();
    }, 5 * 1000);
}
repeatedPrint();
```